# How come some questions have tabs (4 spaces)?

Tags: support, editor

When editing some questions, mostly with code, I discover some of them seems to have "tabs". I mean when I backspace once, it removes 4 spaces. I have been trying to reproduce this but never could.

How do people achieve to add tabs in their questions?

Comment: Probably from tabs in code or something, copied and pasted over.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply prepare your question in your favorite text editor and copy/paste it into the post edit box. Tabs are fine for Markdown. It treats them the same as spaces, so it's all fine.